# How can I delete my profile in The workplace meta?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

Since I figured again that this is a hostile and unproductive place to be, I want to quit my account on "The workplace meta". That said: I cannot find an option to delete my account under account setting.

How to remove my account from this forum?

Comment: Do you want to delete your account purely on meta or on the main site as well? I'm not sure if you can delete _just_ a meta account as it's essentially the same thing as the main site account.

Comment: I already deleted "The workplace"...maybe just a cache glitch. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case I believe your Meta account will vanish at the same time as the main account (24 hours after you request the deletion)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: I couldn't find on the FAQ an answer to this question. It does mention that Meta posts are *not* deleted whatsoever even if site-wide deletion or if the post has negative score or "abandoned"... thus, I posted a question [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391422/332286) to find out

Comment: @PhilipKendall I suspect that as well, seems logical.

Answer (score 2):

> How to remove my account from this forum?

I searched the FAQs and other sources but I couldn't find a "canonical" answer to that. Like I mentioned in comments, I posted a question on Meta.SE asking for clarification ([Are Meta accounts deleted along their "main" account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391422/are-meta-accounts-deleted-along-their-main-account))

So far other users indicate that *yes*, your meta account is deleted as well.

I guess we will be able to answer this question when your main account is deleted and check if this Question got disassociated, and proceed in case it didn't and you also wish this one deleted.

Comment: YUP, it seems it does get deleted as well